# Ruby on Rails: 2 actions on the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to get 2 action showing on the one view.

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
 get "accepted",    to: "users#accepted"
```

users_controller.rb

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @requests = @user.requests
end

def accepted
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @requests = Request.where(:driverid => @user.id).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

I am trying to point these two actions to the users view page.

Ive been playing around with partials and looking at similar questions but cant figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT

show.html.haml

I want the below to be the show action:

```
%h2 Current requests:
- @user.requests.where(:accepted => 'f').each do |request|  
   etc
```

Then the accepted action:

```
- @requests.where(blah blah).each do |request|  
    etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

```
def accepted
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @requests = Request.where(:driverid => @user.id).order("created_at DESC")
  render :show
end
```

EDIT:

In the controller show action:

```
@requests = @user.requests.where(:accepted => 'f')
```

And in the show view:

```
%h2 Current requests:
- @requests.each do |request|  
  # ...
```

Comment: thanks for the help. How would I then display the 2 sets of data in the view page? Ive updated the question to explain what I mean.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully that's what you needed, but if the requirements are actually more complicated then I suggest you go back and re-write your question to explain the full situation more thoroughly.